# How would you say “AKA/as in”?

Tags: expressions, traduction, langage-informel

So in cases like *”He said he’s gonna be late, AKA he’s sleeping,”* or *“I want you to do your homework soon, as in right now,”* how would you translate “AKA” and “as in”?

They both essentially mean “what that really means is X” or that there is another reason why something is happening that is implied.

The closest I can think of is “c’est-à-dire” but that seems too formal for this case.

Are there any colloquial expressions that would fit here?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, *c'est-à-dire* is a good translation. It's not necessarily formal, especially when pronounced *c'tà-dire*.

> Il a dit qu'il allait être en retard, **c'est-à-dire** qu'il dort
>
> Je veux que tu fasses tes devoirs maintenant, **c'est-à-dire** tout de suite.

Another option, less formal, to connote a bit more the sarcasm of your examples, would be *donc en fait*, which means "actually", as when you're revealing a twist:

> Il a dit qu'il allait être en retard, **donc en fait** il dort (he says he'll be late, so let me tell you what this actually means: he's sleeping)

As for "soon, as in right now", there's a better specific expression:

> Je veux que tu fasses tes devoirs **maintenant là tout de suite**.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this phrase:*en clair*. It conveys the idea that it introduces some sort of clarification, and yet is mildly sarcastic. The phrase *en d'autres termes* is also a valid alternative.

> Il a dit qu'il allait être en retard. En clair: il dort.
>
> Je voudrais que tu fasses bientôt tes devoirs, en d'autres termes, que tu les fasses maintenant.